# Is there any further way to simplify this code?

Tags: java, simplify

I feel like there are too many if statements in this, is there any way to further simplify it? I did reduce it a bit, but perhaps there is a more efficient solution? Thanks in advance!

```
Scanner enterPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
double budgetRemaining = 100, itemPrice;

while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
    System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
    System.out.println(itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble());

    if (itemPrice < budgetRemaining) {
        budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;

        if (itemPrice < 0) {
            budgetRemaining += itemPrice;
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        }
    }
    else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
    }

    if (itemPrice == budgetRemaining) {
        budgetRemaining = 0;
        System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is already working, and you just want to have a few pairs of eyes reviewing your working code, then our sister site [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) is a better place for this question.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `if (itemPrice == budgetRemaining)` can completely be replaced by `else`, because you've already asserted the item price is neither less than or greater than the remaining budget, hence it must be equal.

Comment: Replaced that just now. And I'll check out Code Review for future use, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: this not to "simplify", but write from scratch. What is negative price? Comparing double is evil

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to review working code.

Answer (score 2):

**Move negative price check**

Hoist the `itemPrice < 0` check out of the first `if` block. That error check should be present on all code paths, not just the first. Checking for a negative price before subtracting from the budget will keep you from having to add it back in.

```
while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
    System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
    itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble();

    if (itemPrice < 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        continue;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Combine cases**

I would then combine the `<` and `==` cases. Keep the logic as similar as possible: always subtract `itemPrice`. The only difference is that you print a message when done. Since you have a loop condition checking that, you can move the final printout outside of the loop and remove the `if (itemPrice == budgetRemaining)` check entirely.

```
while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
    System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
    itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble();

    if (itemPrice < 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        continue;
    }

    if (itemPrice <= budgetRemaining) {
        budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
    }
    else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
    }
}

System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
```

**Remove redundant `else if`**

Since the `if` and `else if` checks are now straight opposites, the second one can become a simple `else`.

```
if (itemPrice <= budgetRemaining) {
    budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
}
else {
    System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
}
```

**Early exit**

Except, I'd switch the order so that you check for exceeding the budget first. Since we have the `itemPrice < 0` check up front, it makes sense to check for this other error condition up front as well.

```
while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
    System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
    itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble();

    if (itemPrice < 0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        continue;
    }

    if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
        continue;
    }

    budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
}

System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
```

This style of error checking + early exiting with `continue` makes it easy to see what the regular case is: the `budgetRemaining -= itemPrice` statement now lies outside of any condition. It has been promoted to the main code path. It's clear that the other checks and printouts are preconditions.

Alternatively, you could write this with an `if`/`else` chain. Either one works. Now it's just about stylistic preference.

```
if (itemPrice < 0) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
}
else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
}
else {
    budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
}
```

Comment: I suppose was over complicating it by adding different error checks throughout the code. It's much simpler adding the conditions in the beginning with the `continue` statements. This is just what I was hoping to learn, I really appreciate you taking the time! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could just check all negative conditions first to simplify it a bit further.

```
Scanner enterPrice = new Scanner(System.in);
    double budgetRemaining = 100, itemPrice;
    while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
        System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
        System.out.println(itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble());
        if (itemPrice < 0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        } else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
        } else if (itemPrice == budgetRemaining) {
            budgetRemaining = 0;
            System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
        } else {
            budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code

```
while (budgetRemaining > 0) {
        System.out.println("You have a remaining budget of $" + budgetRemaining + ". Please enter price of item:");
        itemPrice = enterPrice.nextDouble();

        if (itemPrice < 1){
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid amount. ");
        }
        else if (itemPrice > budgetRemaining) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, your item exceeds your budget.");
        }
        else{
            budgetRemaining -= itemPrice;
        }
    }    
System.out.println("You have reached your maximum budget. Thank you for shopping with us!");
```

I'm checking if the conditions are true before I remove the value of the item from the budget. If I know the itemPrice is valid: I just carry on the subtraction.

Also, when you're out of money the while-loop will automatically exit, making it unnecessary to check the balance before the actual exit. You might as well print the statement afterwards.

Another minor thing I did was to set itemPice < 1, since I assume the item can't be entirely free.